# Neovim (nvim) unable to find local Python modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, neovim, pyenv, nvim-lspconfig

I'm trying to use `nvim` 0.6 as my IDE and I'm working on a large project that has several local modules (located in the same directory as the main Python script, not installed through `pip`). When I use VSCode, these modules are imported just fine. However, in `nvim`, I get a "could not be resolved" error on every local module. I'm using `pyenv` but the problem is identical if I switch to any other versions; setting Python to system or any other version causes errors for the `pip`-installed modules, since those aren't installed in those environments, but in all environments VSCode loads the local modules correctly and `nvim` does not. What am I missing?

Errors with nvim:
[image]

But in VSCode, everything is loaded fine:
[image]

Both are using Python 3.9.5 via `pyenv` as their interpreter. If I open a Python prompt from the command line I can import those modules and use them no problem:

```
>python
Python 3.9.5 (default, Jul  3 2021, 18:40:06)
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.18.6)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import weewx
>>> dir(weewx)
['CHECK_LOOP', 'CMD_ERROR', 'CONFIG_ERROR', 'CRCError', 'CannotCalculate', 'DB_ERROR', 'END_ARCHIVE_PERIOD', 'Event', 'HardwareError', 'IO_ERROR', 'METRIC', 'METRICWX', 'NEW_ARCHIVE_RECORD', 'NEW_LOOP_PACKET', 'POST_LOOP', 'PRE_LOOP', 'RetriesExceeded', 'STARTUP', 'StopNow', 'US', 'UnitError', 'UnknownAggregation', 'UnknownArchiveType', 'UnknownBinding', 'UnknownDatabase', 'UnknownDatabaseType', 'UnknownType', 'UnsupportedFeature', 'ViolatedPrecondition', 'WakeupError', 'WeeWxIOError', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'absolute_import', 'all_service_groups', 'debug', 'launchtime_ts', 'require_weewx_version', 'time']
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this by manually setting the extraPath variable for the built-in `nvim` LSP in `init.lua`. I'm still not sure how to make this happen automatically.

```
require("lspconfig").pyright.setup {
  settings = {
    python = {
      analysis = {
        extraPaths = {"path/to/desired/modules"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by create `pyrightconfig.json` in the root of my project,
and set the root path in the file like this:

```
{
  "executionEnvironments": [
     {"root": "src"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).